# NoMethodError in ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hav a model called User ( table: users ). I hav populated the table with 2 records. I then used ruby's console to query the records manually by this statement.

```
User.where(:email => 'aa@aa.com')
```

but it is giving me the following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x4d567dc>
    from C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.
0.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1532:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):4
```

can someone tell me where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Rails 2.x right?

The new finders are only available on Rails 3

Comment: yes. i am using Rails 2.0.2.  Oh so thats the problem.. thanks. @apneadiving

Comment: User.find(:all, :conditions => [ "email = ?","aa@aa.com"])

Answer (score 2):

`where` is a new method in ActiveRecord 3.0.  You'll want to either upgrade your version of rails, or stick with `find`